# _pickle.PicklingError, in training networks with num_workers positive

Tags: python, pickle, dataloader

I was training a big dataset, using pytorch Dataset and DataLoader, and this problem appeared. I deleted much of my code to ask this question, and the problem exists, these code can run independently:

```
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

class PGDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.data_x = X
        self.data_y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_x)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data_x[item], self.data_y[item]


def train(dataloader):
    epochs = 5
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i, (data_x, data_y) in enumerate(dataloader):
            pass

    print('Train ended successfully.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, y = np.random.rand(200, 4), np.random.randint(0, 5, 200, dtype='int64')
    train_set = PGDataset(X, y)
    dataloader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=50, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

    train(dataloader)
```

These code seems very standerd for me, and I do not know the reason for this problem.

I am using python==3.9.7, numpy==1.21.5, pytorch==1.10.1.
By the way, I just updated pycharm to 2022.1.

I have tryed this for all day, and searched in many websites, I found:

1. If I set num_workers in dataloader to 0, it's ok. But I need it not to be 0 for a big dataset.
2. In pycharm debug mode, there's also no mistakes.

Why this happen?

Comment: The `PGDataset` is pickled among the different workers. The pickling isn't currently done properly because information on the current module  that  `PGDataset` is on is pickled as `__main__` when the script is run directly. The workers fail to unpickle it because there is really no `__main__` module. You can either move the `PGDataset` to a different module and import it over or set the `__module__` attribute of the class to the name for your script. [Read more on it here](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've read the website. I tried the two ways, importing the class from another module works, but the other doesn't. I added `PGDataset.__module__ = 'mymodule'` (the name of the script is 'mymodule.py') right after the PGDataset instance creating, and the error message changed to `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'mymodule.PGDataset'>: it's not the same object as mymodule.PGDataset`